# NSMutable Array removeObjectAtIndex removing two objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray with 5 objects

```
[0] StateGeographicComponent *  0x0a455ba0
[1] StateGeographicComponent *  0x11c374b0
[2] StateGeographicComponent *  0x08e5f720
[3] StateGeographicComponent *  0x11c15430
[4] StateGeographicComponent *  0x0a458f20
```

After executing the following line of code:

```
[self.gameComponents removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Instead of simply removing the object at index 0 and sliding everything up an index as I'd expect.  The object at index [0] is set to nil AND the object at index [4] is removed.

```
[0] id  0x00000000
[1] StateGeographicComponent *  0x11c374b0
[2] StateGeographicComponent *  0x08e5f720
[3] StateGeographicComponent *  0x11c15430
```

Quite perplexing to me..

Comment: Use NSLog to do the before/after dumps, or use `po` in the console.  The debug display is likely confused.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks, I was getting a bit ahead of myself and debugging without actually seeing if the debugger was displaying erroneous data.  LVM seems to be quite buggy!

Comment: Yeah, someone was asking me a couple of days ago why I mostly use `po` in the console.  This is why.

Answer (score -4):

Use the following lines of code

```
[self.gameComponents replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNull null]];
[self.gameComponents removeLastObject];
```

The first line of code replaces the object with singleton instance of `NSNull` and the second line of code removes the last object from the array.

Comment: Neither of which the OP wanted to do.

Comment: This seems to be unwanted!